# How to measure Latency between client to bot and bot to Client (Not response time)

Tags: botframework, azure-application-insights, slack, azure-bot-service

I have created at bot for slack and deployed to Azure, for this bot I have a client requirement, My client wants to measure latency between slack client to Bot and vice a versa. i.e only time taken by user message to reach to Bot and 
time taken by response to slack user. I have been exploring Azure application insight from three days , but could not find any helpful service. I can not change my bot code , Is there any way in azure service by that I can monitor latency?

Comment: "My client wants to measure latency between slack client to Bot" < so it can't be achieved from Azure, as Slack client is not on Azure (how would Azure know when the message was sent?). I think you will not have an answer to do this

Comment: @NicolasR , I thought of the same...But request header contains the time stamp of request generated from client. Maybe Azure app insight can catch this for latency....or something like this..! I don't know.

Comment: Yes but as you don't know how this timestamp is generated, it will not be really useful...