# How to measure Latency of calling a API from Bot framework and time taken to receive the response. i.e. request/response travelling time

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-application-insights

I have created a bot for slack and deployed to Azure, I am making some API calls to another server from this BOT, for this bot I have a client requirement, My client wants to measure the time taken by request to reach to server and time taken by response to come back to Bot. (only time taken by request/response to reach to either side . I have been exploring Azure application insight from three days , but could not find any helpful service. I can not change my bot code , Is there any way in azure service by that I can monitor latency?

Here is simple diagram:-

```
Bot ----t1----> Server
    <---t2-----
```

I don't want response time taken to process at Server side (No calculation time ) Just request/response travelling time.

Comment: you mean... you're looking for [tcping](https://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php)?

Comment: does the bot framework not already do this via application insights `TrackDependency` calls?  outbound requests should *theoretically* already be tracked for you as dependencies, so you'd see the time taken to execute that call already?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to measure Latency between client to bot and bot to Client (Not response time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49538323/how-to-measure-latency-between-client-to-bot-and-bot-to-client-not-response-tim)

Comment: @evilSnobu ..may be yes.

Comment: @JohnGardner .. Application insights Tracks the whole execution time of sending the request , processing the request and receiving the response.. I need only request and response travelling time. To check the n/w latencies..

Comment: you already asked the same question, don't you ?

Comment: @NicolasR .. Both Seems to be same question , but are not.
1. How to measure Latency between client to bot and bot to Client (Not response time)
2. How to measure Latency of calling a API from Bot framework and time taken to receive the response. i.e. request/response travelling time

Simple flow Diagram: 

     (  skype ---- t1 ----> Bot --- t2 -->API Server )

AND VICE A VERSA 

    (  skype <--- t4 ---- Bot <--- t3 ------API Server  )

Answer (score 0):

Ganesh,

What you seem to be asking is how long it takes the API to process a request and return a response. Nothing to do with your bot.

My suggestion would be to create performance tests against the API directly using a tool such as Jmeter. This will give you average response times for say 10,000 requests and plot out on nice graphs etc.

If you need a help doing this, I could write it up for you in step by step instructions.

Let me know.

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: No, What I want in short is - Time required to travel request from user to Bot and time taken by response to reach to User from Bot. i.e Network latency.